# Anyway to inject JS into an iframe prior its doc.ready event?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, iframe

**What i'm trying to achieve is:**

1. Dynamically load an iframe into the page (same domain)
2. Before it gets it first life cycle events (ready, load) - inject a function to the global window scope of the iframe.

**I tried the following:**

1. Register to iframe `document.ready` event - problem is `frameElement.contentWindow` still `null`.
2. Register to iframe `load` event - too late, the iframe tries to call the future to be injected function.

Code:

```
var element = $("#myframe");
var frameElement = element.get(0);
element.ready(function(){
      //inject function to iframe
      console.log("frame window?", frameElement.contentWindow);
      frameElement.contentWindow["my_func"] = function(){...};                                
});
```

Any ideas on how this can be achieved?

Comment: Is the iframe being loaded from the same domain as the main page? If it is a different domain, you are out of luck. If it is the same domain, you could download the HTML source for the iframe URL with a `$.ajax()` call (i.e. *don't* load it directly into the iframe), then modify the HTML string, and finally load that HTML string directly into the iframe. But if it is the same domain, you could also modify the code on your server to deliver the HTML code you want with your function already added.

Answer (score 0):

You can use HTML5 window messaging to send data back and forth between iframe and its parent window.

In the iframe:

```
window.addEventListener("message", receiveMessage, false);
function receiveMessage(event) {
    if (event.origin !== "http://yourDoamin.com") //for security
        return;
    //use somethingYouNeed by accessing event.data 
}
```

In the main page after loading iframe:

```
//send somethingYouNeed to the iframe    
iframe.postMessage(somethingYouNeed);
```

More information:
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Window/postMessage